# CKEditor adding backslashes to HTML tags with attributes

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

CKEditor is escaping all the HTML attributes when I submit the page with backslashes.

```
<img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckfinder/userfiles/images/a.jpg\" style=\"width: 600px; height: 450px;\" />
```

It's working fine in my local machine and the issue is happening only in the live server.

What could be the problem?

Comment: seems like something with php Magic Quotes! am not much into php.. can anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it using sample code from php Manual

```
function strip_magic_slashes($str) {    return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($str) : $str; }
```